# Sketching the vector $u - v + w$ using vector addition and subtraction?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am currently trying to do vector addition and subtraction and I am wondering if what I am doing is correct in any way?

So given, the graph with the three vectors drawn out, we have these following details:[image]

I am asked to perform **u - v + w**

So, here is what I figured I should do to try and get some sort of answer:

Vector **u** component : $$(5,-5)$$

Vector **v** terminal point is (-5,-3), but we are multiplying it by a negative so its terminal point changes to: $$(5,3)$$

Vector **w** terminal point is: $$(-2,5)$$

So, after doing all that I came to a conclusion that it would look like this:

[image]

Clarification:

I am given the picture and I am asked to perform u - v + w on it.

Comment: nice picture :)

Comment: Are the vectors represented by the red lines or the end points?

Comment: The vectors are the lines themselves, but my approach might confuse you since I used the terminal points to try and do it.

Comment: You need to draw $-v$ as parallel to $v$ snd starting at the end point of $u$ (which is based at $0$).

Comment: So what I did was completely wrong then?

Comment: Well, you should have (a zero based)  $-v = (10,-2)$. Your $v$ is vertical.

Comment: Instead of computing, draw lines on paper. Then, when you have figured it out, do the computation.

Comment: Another way is to note that $u-v+w = u+v+w-2v$. Since the drawing already has $u+v+w$ you can start there and follow $-2v$. You should end at $(18,1)$ if I computed correctly.

Comment: To be honest, I'm really confused with the negative v, should I be drawing -v starting at the terminal point of u to the coordinate (10,-2)?

Comment: How did you get (18,1)?